# Save all output to a file - Shell Bash

Tags: bash, shell

is it possible to save all the output from a created bash shell file?
Basically the file makes calculations and I would like to save all the output of this created bash shell.

**Basically I want to save all the output to a file or sample the last 10 outputs (for example)**

Comment: How about using `>`? Or what do you mean?

Comment: Basically I want to save all the output to a file or sample the last 10 outputs (for example)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ./yourscript.sh > outputfile.txt
```

Where yourscript.sh is the bash shell file you've created and outputfile.txt is the file you want to write the output to.